# Zoomable window with buttons in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Tkinter window that has many buttons in it and it is zoomable/moveable.
This is my current code but I don't know how to let users zoom with a mouse scroll or a button or something like that :

```
from tkinter import *
main = Tk()
main.geometry("500x500")

for y in range(50):
    for x in range(50):
        exec(f"buttonx{x}y{y} = Button(main, text=\"\", borderwidth=0.5).place(x={x*10}, y={y*10}, height=10, width=10)")

main.mainloop()
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ways to zoom, keys or mouse, you might want to take a look at `bind()`. [Events and Bindings](https://web.archive.org/web/20200717100008/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

As for the creation of the buttons I would suggest a more common way of saving the button references using a two-dimensional list:

```
field = []
for y in range(50):
    row = []
    for x in range(50):
        b = Button(main, borderwidth=0.5)
        b.place(x=x*10, y=y*10, height=10, width=10)
        row.append(b)
    field.append(row)
```

This makes it easier to access the buttons.

But why buttons though? When I run this program it's really slow. Does it have to be buttons or are you planning to have something else there later?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I was wanted to make something like [r/Place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place_(Reddit)), so there are many buttons (pixels) on the screen, and the user has to zoom and click on them to change their colors to make art or something like that. It's going to be a multiplayer game.
But I still do not understand exactly what to do to zoom in on these buttons.

Comment: I recommend you try to work with an image instead of buttons. With the [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library you have functions for changing image size, cropping, changing pixels and more. As for tracking and responding to mouse position and scrolling you can use the `bind()` method.